# Find all incongruent roots modulo $13$ of $x^4+x^2+x+1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find all incongruent roots modulo $13$ of $x^4+x^2+x+1$

So by Lagrange theorem, there should be $4$, because the highest degree is $4$ and the coefficient in front of it is $1$, which divides $13$.

The solution says that $7$ is the only solution but doesn't say why or how they found it

[image]

---

**Edit** Below was the theorem cited in earlier drafts (discussed in comments)

[image]

Comment: according to my brute force calculations, $\color{red}6$ is the only zero of $x^4+x^2+x+1$ in $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12\}$ modulo $13$

Comment: yea I dunno book says 7, but is that how you can check? Just brute force all relative primes less than x?

Comment: Difficult to answer, for the source of your confusion is in the dark. I am not aware of any result telling that $1\mid 13$ should imply that this polynomial has 4 zeros in $\Bbb{Z}_{13}$. For the better, I suppose, for this polynomial has only one such zero. J.W.Tanner got it right, modulo $13$ the polynomial factors as
$$x^4+x^2+x+1=(x+7)(x^3+6x^2+11x+2)$$ with the cubic factor irreducible. Which is equivalent to $x=-7=6$ being the only zero in $\Bbb{Z}_{13}$. As a quartic the polynomial has four zeros, but the other three are in an extension field $\Bbb{F}_{13^3}$.

Comment: The last phenomenon being somewhat analogous to two of the zeros of $(x-1)(x^2+1)\in\Bbb{R}[x]$ being complex numbers as opposed to real.

Comment: I'll add the theorem to the question

Comment: The theorem you listed requires that $4\mid 13-1=12$, so $1\mid 13$ is rather irrelevant. Also that theorem is *only about the specific polynomial $x^4-1$*. It does not apply to all polynomials of degree four.

Comment: I agree with @JyrkiLahtonen:  Theorem 9.7 refers to polynomial $x^d-1$, not $x^4+x^2+x+1$

Comment: Sorry I posted the wrong one the right one is up now

Comment: Theorem 9.6 says there are _at most_ $n$ roots; there could be fewer

Comment: Right, but still doesn't really explain how they found the solution besides brute force.

Comment: By changing the theorem(image) you make it much harder to understand the above discussion based on the prior theorem. Please don't do that. Better to update with the new one and mark it as an edit.

Comment: Actually finding those zeros is more taxing. For a small prime such as $p=13$ brute forcing like J.W.Tanner did it may be the fastest way. There are more efficient methods for finding them (for larger primes), see [this old thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/893044/11619), but they require more advanced algorithms. I wouldn't bother with those at this point in your studies.

Answer (score 3):

By Fermat $\,x^{12}\!-\!1\,$ has all elements $\not\equiv 0$ as roots so taking its gcd with  $\,f(x)\,$ will yield all its roots. The Euclidean algorithm has the monic remainder sequence $\, x^3\!-\!x^2\!-\!6x\!-\!1,\,$ $\,x^2\!+\!x\!-\!3,\,$ $\,x\!+\!7,\,$ $0,\,$ so the gcd $= x\!+\!7,\,$ thus $\,f(x)\,$ has unique root $\,x \equiv -7\equiv 6$.

**Remark** $ $ We can also use gcds this way to find higher degree factors and do irreducibility tests, e.g. see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3214866/242) and its links.

Note that Lagrange's theorem yields only an *upper bound* on the number of roots of a polynomial, e.g. $\bmod 13\!:\ f(x) = x^{13}-x+1\,$ has no roots since $\,f(x) \equiv 1\,$ for all $x,\,$ by little Fermat.

Comment: I guess you implicitly ruled out $0$ as a root of $x^4+x^2+x+1$ because its constant coefficient is non-zero

Comment: @J.W.T Correct, I thought that would be obvious to readers at this level.